# Convert Base Model To Sub View Model

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have a model named DriverStaistic and a view model which inherits from it
the view model doesn't contain any extra properties it's just an empty inheritance of DriverStaistic, the reason I'm doing that is that I receive the model objects from an external library and I want to keep coupling to the minimum.
since the base and the sub class contains the same properties I was wondering if we there's a neat way to convert between them other than using the lambda expression which requires me to modify it every time I add or omit a property

I have come out with this solution using reflection but I believe it will present performance issues in the future.
can anyone come with a better suggestion?

```
public static void FromDriverStatistic(this DriverStatisticsVm viewModel, object model)
{
    bool isDriverStatistic = model is DriverStatistic;

    if(!isDriverStatistic)
        throw  new InvalidCastException();

    var modelProperties = model.GetType().GetProperties();
    foreach (var property in modelProperties)
    {
        property.SetValue(viewModel, property.GetValue(model));
    }
}
```

Comment: "I receive the model objects from an external library and I want to keep coupling to the minimum" which results in the need to do dirty hacks like this?

Answer (score 0):

> I have come out with this solution using reflection but I believe it will present performance issues in the future. can anyone come with a better suggestion?

The option is to set all properties one by one, i.e.:

```
public static void FromDriverStatistic(this DriverStatisticsVm viewModel,  DriverStatistic model)
{
    viewModel.PropertyA = model.PropertyA;
    viewModel.PropertyB = model.PropertyB;
    //and so on...
}
```

The drawback with this approach is obviously that you must know all property names at compile-time and modify the mapper method whenever a property is added, removed or renamed from either of the classes.

The other option is to use reflection but the drawback with this is that you lose the compile-time safety and some performance.

You need to make a trade off decision. If there are only a few properties to be set, the price you will pay for using reflection won't be that high. You should also be able to re-use the same method or logic for several different view model/model type mappings. So if you want flexibility, stick with using reflection. If performance and compile-time safety is critical, don't.

Comment: certainly that's not better than using lambda expression on the contrary I could have made use of some of nice performance capabilities of the lambda expression